# Project a level set onto a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, projection

I have a level surface in $(x,y,z)$ space. For concreteness, let's say

$\frac{1}{r^2}x^2 + \left(\frac{\sin \theta}{r}\right)^2y^2 + \left(\frac{\cos \theta}{r}\right)^2z^2 + \frac{2 \cos \theta \sin \theta}{r^2} xy = 1$

which is describes a circle with radius $r$ initially in the $xz$ plane that is tilted by angle $\theta$. How can I get the level surface of the corresponding projected ellipse in the $xy$ plane?

In other words, if I have an observer at $z = \infty$, how can I describe the equation of the ellipse they will see?

Comment: The space you describe is mots likely to be a filled ellipse since the smooth manifold it describes is of dimension 2. Otherwise just see $z$ as a parameter that can vary, this gives you $\left\{(x,y)\mid {x^2 +\sin^2\theta \, y^2 + 2\cos\theta \sin \theta \, xy}\leqslant r^2 \right\}$

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace this was my first thought, but I don't think it's correct. This appears to simply set z=0, which would solve for the intersections of my level surface with the $z=0$ plane, which is not quite what I want. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: I'm writing an answer to explain, it can be tricky

Comment: Keep in mind that algebraic varieties are not preserved by projection, you will always get a semi-algebraic variety (basically instead of equalities with polynomials, you have inequalities)

Answer (score 0):

So as I stated in my comment, your set $S$ defined by your equation equation (that I will rewrite for more convenience)
$$x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 + \cos^2(\theta) z^2 + 2\cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) xy = r^2$$
Defines a $2$-dimensional smooth manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (that will very probably look like a deformed sphere) so its projection parallel to the $z$ axis on the $x,y$ plane will be a filled ellipse.

---

Now the projection $p$ is defined to be $p((x,y,z)) = (x,y)$, thus if $\cos(\theta)\neq 0$
$$\begin{align*}
p(S) &= \bigcup_{z \in \mathbb{R}}\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 + \cos^2(\theta) z^2 + 2\cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) xy = r^2 \right\}\\
&=\bigcup_{z' \geqslant 0}\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 + z' + 2\cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) xy = r^2 \right\}\\
&=\bigcup_{z' \geqslant 0}\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 + 2\cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) xy = r^2 - z' \right\}\\
&=\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 + 2\cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) xy \leqslant r^2 \right\}
\end{align*}$$

Now let's rewrite this latter inéquation.

$$\begin{align*}
&x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 + 2\cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) xy \leqslant r^2 \\
\iff& (1-\cos^2(\theta))x^2 + \cos^2(\theta) x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 + 2\cos(\theta) \sin (\theta) xy \leqslant r^2 \\
\iff& (\sin \theta \, x)^2 + (\cos \theta \, x + \sin \theta \, y)^2 \leqslant r^2 \\
\end{align*}$$

---

Now we have two cases, first let us suppose that $\sin \theta \neq 0$. This equation is just the equation of a disk in the basis $((\sin \theta ,0), (\cos \theta , \sin \theta)$. Basically the basis change matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\sin \theta & 0 \\
\cos \theta & \sin \theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

Its inverse is
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\sin^{-1} \theta & 0 \\
-\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin^2 \theta} & \sin^{-1} \theta
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{sin^2 \theta} \begin{pmatrix}
\sin \theta & 0 \\
-\cos \theta & \sin \theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus $p(S) = A\cdot D_r$ where $D$ denotes the disk of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so a filled  rotated ellipse.

---

Now if $\sin \theta = 0$, we have $(\cos\theta \, x)^2 \leqslant r^2$ i.e. $|x| \leqslant \frac{r}{|\cos\theta|}$ so your solution space is $\left[-\frac{r}{|\cos\theta|},\frac{r}{|\cos\theta|} \right] \times \mathbb{R}$, so basically a large vertical line.

---

Now if $\cos \theta = 0$,

$$\begin{align*}
p(S) &= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + \sin^2(\theta) y^2 = r^2 \right\}\\
 &= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \right\}
\end{align*}$$

So it is a circle of radius r.

---

Let us get back to the study of the ellipse defined by $A(\theta) D_r$, to know it better it suffices to compute the polar decomposition of $A = OS$ with $O = O_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $s \in S_n^{++}(\mathbb{R})$. More particularly what is interesting to study is the eigenvalues of $S$ which means the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^T A$, this will give you the distorsion of the circle to make your ellipse.

Let us compute
$$A^T A = \frac{1}{\sin^4 \theta} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -sin \theta \cos \theta \\
-sin \theta \cos \theta & \sin^{2} \theta
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{\sin^4 \theta }R$$
This will of course be diagonalizable and the characteristic polynomial of $R$ is
$$\begin{align*}
\chi_R(X) &= (X-1)(X-\sin^2\theta) - \sin^2\theta \cos^2 \theta \\
&= X^2 -(1 + \sin^2\theta)X +sin^2 \theta (1-\cos^2\theta) \\
&= X^2 -(1 + \sin^2\theta)X +sin^4 \theta 
\end{align*}$$

Now search for its roots,
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta &= (1+\sin^2 \theta)^2 - 4 \sin^4 \theta \\
&= 1 + 2 \sin^2 \theta-3\sin^4 \theta \\
&= (1-\sin^2\theta)(1 + 3 \sin^2\theta) \\
&= \cos^2\theta (1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta)
\end{align*}$$

This gives you two distinct eigenvalues
$$r_\pm = \frac{1 + \sin^2\theta \pm |\cos \theta| \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta}}{2}$$

So the eigenvalues of $S$ are
$$s_\pm = \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\sqrt{\frac{1 + \sin^2\theta \pm |\cos \theta| \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta}}{2}}$$

Which means the distortion (length of big axis / length of small axis) will be
$$\begin{align*}
d &=\sqrt{\frac{1 + \sin^2\theta + |\cos \theta| \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta}}{1 + \sin^2\theta - |\cos \theta| \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta}}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{ \left( 1 + \sin^2\theta + |\cos \theta| \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta }\right)^2 }{r_+ r-}}\\
&=\frac{ 1 + \sin^2\theta + |\cos \theta| \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta } }{\sqrt{4\sin^4 \theta}}\\
&= \frac{  1 + \sin^2\theta + |\cos \theta| \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2 \theta } }{2\sin^2 \theta}
\end{align*} $$

So basically your ellipse will have $r_+$ for big axis and $r_-$ for small axis.

The computation of the angle is possible but very fastidious.